# function containing 2 loops

Tags: swift, swift3

Have a sorting function here and when I change the -- decrementer to `-= 1` that gets rid of one error but I still get the syyntax error.

```
 func iSortBort(myList: Array) -> Array {

    var extract = myList

    for firstIndex in 0..<extract.count {

        let key = extract[firstIndex]

        for var secondIndex = firstIndex; secondIndex > -1; secondIndex--1 {
```

Comment: This has _NOTHING_ to do with the fact that it is a loop in a loop. `for var secondIndex = firstIndex; secondIndex > -1; secondIndex--1` That is a C-style for loop. You need to use `for...in` instead.

Comment: It's best if you try to maintain a neutral tone in your question, adding in comments like "your small little world" will only garner further downvoting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`stride` is indeed the way to go. Also, it seems like you would benefit from using `enumerate()`. Try this:

```
for (firstIndex, key) in extract.enumerate() {
    for secondIndex in firstIndex.stride(through: 0, by: -1) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: @TokyoToo You're welcome! People here can be a bit harsh for beginners. Not everyone is, though. Just keep learning, and soon enough you'll find all of this stuff easy. :)

Comment: Replace `through` by `to`. This might be a bit confusing, but `stride` basically has two versions. One for `<=` and `>=` (`through`), the other for `<` and `>` (`to`). See [here](http://swiftdoc.org/v2.2/type/AnyRandomAccessIndex/#dash-anchor-9). So you can either replace `through` by `to`, or replace `extract.count` by `extract.count - 1`.

Comment: By the way, you can simply say `by: 1` instead of `by: +1`. :)

Comment: @TokyoToo No, you didn't do it right. Now you have three loops. Get rid of the outer one, and also get rid of the `key` declaration, the line with the warning. Then it should work.

Answer (score 4):

In case of doubt, any C-style `for`, regardless of its position or nesting level, can be trivially changed to a `while` loop:

```
var secondIndex = firstIndex
while secondIndex > -1 {
    defer { i -= 1 }
    // loop body
}
```

though you might be able to get away with `stride` in your case. (I don't remember how to use it off my head though, especially not in Swift 3.)

Answer (score 2):

check this out: http://bjmiller.me/post/137624096422/on-c-style-for-loops-removed-from-swift-3

like for decrementing:

```
for secondIndex in (0...firstIndex).reverse() {
    print("comparing \(key) and \(myList[secondIndex])")
    if key < extract[secondIndex] {
        extract.removeAtIndex(secondIndex + 1)
        extract.insert(key, atIndex: secondIndex)
    }
}
```

Comment: there is really no difference in case you only -1. It's just how do you adapt it.

Answer (score -4):

The correct answer is to just use the included Swift `sort` function. That's all your code does so why re-invent the wheel? (Poorly btw, your code compares each element to itself which is totally unnecessary, and it loads up `extract` and then moves the elements around in it when it would be better to just build up the array as you go along.)

Comment: This does not solve the general problem, it's rude, and it doesn't try to understand why this code is being written at all.